# Amazon Aurora RDS (serveless) - How to match an ACU in terms of CPU number and memory

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

I need to migrate an Amazon RDS back to on-premises envoriment. How to How to match an ACU in terms of CPU number and memory?

My instance has:

```
Minimum capacity
1 ACUs (2 GiB)
Maximum capacity
10 ACUs (20 GiB)
```

This means I need 20Gib of memory, but how many CPU?

Amazon says:

> Database capacity is measured in Aurora Capacity Units (ACUs). 1 ACU
> provides 2 GiB of memory and corresponding compute and networking.

Ok, so one ACU is one CPU? Can anybody help me with that? what is "corresponding compute"??

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the [server instance classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html) behind Aurora sport 8 GiB per CPU core. The "serverless" class is not documented, but I think it's safe to assume it follows the same principle (which, incidentally, is what's commonly recommended for other databases, like Postgres and Db2).

[Some people](https://fauna.com/blog/compare-aws-aurora-serverless-v2-architecture-features-pricing-vs-fauna), however, think it's more like 4 GiB per core.